# Appending to lists stored in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

If I want to create a dictionary that looks like this:

```
switches = {'s1': {'port1': [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]], 'port2': [2,2,2]}}
```

I have tried:

```
switches = {}
switches['s1'] = {}
switches['s1']['port1'] = [0, 0, 0]
switches['s1']['port1'] = [1, 1, 1]
switches['s1']['port2'] = [2, 2, 2]
```

However, `[1, 1, 1]` overwrites `[0, 0, 0]`!

How can I have the value `[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]` for the key `'port1'`?

Comment: hint. Use `append` when wanting to *append* to a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on idjaw's comment and keksnicoh's answer, I think you can make your life a little bit easier by using a `defaultdict`.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
>>> d['s1']['port1'].append([0, 0, 0])
>>> d['s1']['port1'].append([1, 1, 1])
>>> d['s1']['port2'].append([2, 2, 2])
>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f5d217e2b90>, {'s1': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'port2': [[2, 2, 2]], 'port1': [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]})})
```

You can use it just like a regular dictionary:

```
>>> d['s1']
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'port2': [[2, 2, 2]], 'port1': [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]})
>>> d['s1']['port1']
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your dict keys may be some kinda list, so you can append multiple values to it.

```
switches['s1'] = {}
switches['s1']['port1'] = list()
switches['s1']['port1'].append([0, 0, 0])
switches['s1']['port1'].append([1, 1, 1])
```

Also if you add single values you may also put them into a list so you can access the dict always by the same way:

```
switches['s1']['port2'] = list([2,2,2])
```

Getting the first port would be

```
print(switches['s1']['portN'][0]
```