# Update a list in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a nested dicts. Here is my dict:

```
org_query = {"query": {"bool": {"must": [],"must_not": []}}}
```

I want to update another dict inside the nested dict. Here's the dict i want to add:

```
query_form =  { "match_phrase": { "name": "steve" }}
```

Required Output:

```
org_query = {"query": {"bool": {"must": [{ "match_phrase": { "name": "steve" }],"must_not": []}}}
```

I found this [Update value of a nested dictionary of varying depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232943/update-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-of-varying-depth) 
but it updates the value. In my case, i want to update the entire dict to the list in the key of the nested dict. How to make it possible.

Comment: by what logic is it decided where the query form should go?

Comment: Append the dictionary in the list `org_query['query']['bool']['must'].append(query_form)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending to lists stored in a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533315/appending-to-lists-stored-in-a-nested-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, that would be:

```
org_query["query"]["bool"]["must"].append(query_form)
```

> More here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp